# Using ECQL filter on user form using GeoServer and OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, javascript

I know this is more of a JS question (skills of which I am inadequately inept) but it is using OpenLayers and GeoServer.

I am trying to apply a filter with a user form on a Layer, but am not sure why it is not working.  If I manually write the code into the CQL_FILTER, it works, but it won't work with the UpdateFilter button.

```
function init_map() {

    var layerExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds( -9816656, 5296800, -9772016, 5345759);

    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', 
            {'restrictedExtent': layerExtent});
    basemap = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Simple OSM Map");
    map.addLayer(basemap);
    markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.setCenter(
        new OpenLayers.LonLat(-71.147, 42.472).transform(
            new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            map.getProjectionObject()
        ), 12
    );

    var tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "Verizon Cell Towers", "http://mpdflash:7070/geoserver/Milwaukee/wms",
                {
                    LAYERS: 'Milwaukee:Verizon Cell Towers',
                    tiled: true,
                    transparent: true
                },
                {
                    displayOutsideMaxExtent: true,
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    yx : {'EPSG:6948' : false}
                } 
            );  

    map.addLayer(tiled);

    tiled.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': "filter"})
}

function updateFilter(){
        var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    }

function resetFilter() {
        document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
        updateFilter();
    }
```

and

```
<div id="toolbar">
            <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
            <img id="updateFilterButton" src="http://mpdflash:7070/geoserver/openlayers/img/east-mini.png" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter"/>
            <img id="resetFilterButton" src="http://mpdflash:7070/geoserver/openlayers/img/cancel.png" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter"/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit 3 places in your code.

1) Declare the **tiled** variable at the global scope before your **init_map** function:

```
var tiled;
function init_map() {
   ...
}
```

2) Remove the var in front of **tiled** when you create your WMS layer inside your **init_map** function:

```
tiled = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
   ...
);
```

3) Use the mergeNewParams function in your **updateFilter** function like this:

```
function updateFilter(){
    var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    tiled.mergeNewParams({'CQL_FILTER': filter})
}
```

Comment: Just a quick clarification for my own help.  Why do I need to declare the tiled variable before the init function?  That was the only change that I hadn't tried.

Comment: So you can access the tiled variable outside the scope of the init_map function. If you declare the tiled variable in the init_map you can only access it in the scope of the init_map function.